# How to resolve cross site scripting issue in jsp file

Tags: jsp, xss, cross-site

How to resolve xss issue on below line in a jsp page

```
        form:options items="${some}"
```

I have tried like below in sample.jsp

```
        form:options items="${some}" htmlEscape="true"
```

still xss issue exists.

If tried like below in sample.jsp

```
         form:options items="${fn:escapeXml(some)}"
```

now xss issue no more exsits but then application is not working for this page sample.jsp...showing like invalid type of string for option items.
Any help is appreciated..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question did not make sense. You refered to some `sample.jsp` as if you have included the code, but you have not included the code (because you did not notate the code blocks). Also you had included code in the question title which is a really bad idea. I've edited your question to fix these problems. You also left out the `jsp` tag which means that no-one following `jsp` would try to help you.

Comment: Please include the code you referred to so that it is possible for someone to assist you.